# Detaching an entity and saving the context on another attempt

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I am trying to handle a situation in a bulk insert process where there may be entities with the same primary key, which of course is going to make **SaveChanges** throw an exception.

Here's what I have:

```
try
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
    _context.Dispose();
    _context = null;
    _context = SelectContext<T>();
    _commitCount = 0;
}
catch (System.Data.UpdateException updateEx)
{
    //Remove from _context all the entries that errored in the SaveChange() process...
    if (updateEx.StateEntries != null)
    {
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntry in updateEx.StateEntries)
        {

            if ((System.Data.EntityState)stateEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("EntityState").GetValue(stateEntry.Entity, null) != System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
            {
                _context.Detach(stateEntry.Entity);
            }
         }

}

//Save context changes again this time without erroneous entries...
try
{
     _context.SaveChanges();
     _context.Dispose();
     _context = null;
     _context = SelectContext<T>();
     _commitCount = 0;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {                  
   //Welp, at the point, I'm clueless...
 }
```

If I look in the ObjectStateManager, the entity is indeed removed (the count goes down by the number of time the foreach loop is iterated.)

But it still throws an exception on the second attempt, whinning about a dupe PK.

I tought detaching an entity was the same is if it was never in the context in the first place. Do I need to do something else ?

Thanks.

Comment: any reason you don't want to check if object exists before save?

Comment: can you check if entity exists in db before adding? i think it is better than to add, and detach in catch

Comment: Why would I check if something is in a database when I'm about to insert it ? The duplicate primary key error comes from having two entities (yet to be comitted to the database) or more with the same PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing in my case:

```
_context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(stateEntry.Entity, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
_context.ApplyOriginalValues<T>(entityType, (T)stateEntry.Entity);
_context.Detach(stateEntry.Entity);
```

After that, I'm able to save the context changes.

Answer (score 1):

`Deatch` doesn't fully undo the changes. Per the msdn doc "Only the entity is removed; if there are any related objects that are being tracked by the same ObjectStateManager, those will not be detached automatically."

Only the entity you pass to detach is removed. Other changes will cause a failure. Will there be contention for you db? If this application is the only thing making changes to the db you can undo changes with `context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, object);` otherwise, it's a bit more complicated.

You have to do something like this;

```
 var entry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)object).EntityKey);

  for (int i = 0; i < entry.OriginalValues.FieldCount; i++)

{

     entry.CurrentValues.SetValue(i, entry.OriginalValues[i]);

}

entry.AcceptChanges();
```

The above code uses the `ObjectSateManager` to return all modified objects to their original states, after that `context.SaveChanges();` shoudl succeed.

You may also find this useful http://dotnetadventurer.blogspot.com/2010/09/discarding-changes-to-objectcontext-in.html I haven't tried his code and I usually initialize my context differently so I'm not sure if it will work with your example but it's very simple so if it does, it's the route I would go.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in my case: